# Unity Convert function into a Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm having an issue with an image I'm trying to write to disc (the image size should be 1280x1024 but it's saving it as 512x512) and I'm wondering if a Coroutine might solve the problem? If so, I'm completely new to Coroutines, could someone illustrate how the code I've written below would be converted into a Coroutine? Many thanks.

```
// Saves texture as PNG file.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class SaveTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public RenderTexture tex;
    int tWidth, tHeight;

    int getTextureWidth(int texWidth)
    {
        return tex.width;
    }

    int getTextureHeight(int texHeight)
    {
        return tex.height;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        tWidth = getTextureWidth(tex.width);
        tHeight = getTextureHeight(tex.height);

        Debug.Log("RenderTexture Width: " + tWidth + ", RenderTexture Height: " + tHeight);
    }

    Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(tWidth, tHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        RenderTexture.active = rTex;
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tWidth, tHeight), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }

    // Save Texture as PNG
    public void SaveTexturePNG()
    {
        Texture2D myTexture = tex.toTexture2D();

        tWidth = getTextureWidth(myTexture.width);
        tHeight = getTextureHeight(myTexture.height);

        Debug.Log("Texture2D Width: " + tWidth + ", Texture2D Height: " + tHeight);

        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = myTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.Destroy(myTexture);

        Debug.Log(bytes.Length);

        // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../AnimalTexture/AnimalTexture.png", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a coroutine fix this issue? You simply pass incorrect arguments or have a math problem somewhere. I guess the problem is in `getTextureWidth()` and `getTextureHeight()`, where you don't return the passed parameter (why would you create a method that simply returns its parameter anyway?), but return `tex.width`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with coroutines. The problem is likely the `EncodeToPNG()` function and I beleive that the only fix is to make a native plugin with C++ that converts `Texture.GetNativeTexturePt()`  to PNG.  You will need libpng. It's hard to do but very possible.

Comment: i thought that maybe it wasn't finishing writing the file to disc and a pause might help. Guess not. Can you see why I might be having this problem?

Comment: I really don't know why and suspect the `EncodeToPNG()` function.